# How can I extract a list of terms with functions in terms of a specific variable

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

I have an expression in the following form:

```
a f[x] + b Exp[g[x, y]] + r[z] f[y] + f[y] Sin[h[x, y, z]^2] + r[z] Log[t[z, y]]
```

I want to extract an expression containing only the terms that are a function of x, i.e:

```
a f[x] + b Exp[g[x, y]] + f[y] Sine[h[x, y, z]^2]
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr = a f[x] + b Exp[g[x, y]] + r[z] f[y] + f[y] Sin[h[x, y, z]^2] + 
  r[z] Log[t[z, y]]

Select[expr, ! FreeQ[#, x] &]
```

$$b e^{g(x,y)}+f(y) \sin \left(h(x,y,z)^2\right)+a f(x)$$

Comment: you could also use `Select[Not @* FreeQ[x]] @ expr` (+1)